# Forward declaration and delete

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

My teacher told me to do a final homework. I need to make a list of things in C++ (cant use boost, STL, etc). My Stuff class HAVE TO be defined AFTER a List class. Little sample what I tried:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Stuff;

class List
{
    private :

        Stuff *s;
        int n;

    public :

        List(int n)
        {
            this->n = n;
            s = new Stuff[n];
        }

        ~List()
        {
            delete[] s;
            s = NULL;
            n = 0;
        }

};

class Stuff
{
    private :

        string name;
        double price;

    public :

        Stuff(){}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I know, that:

> "If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of
>   deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a
>   deallocation function, the behavior is undefined."

But how ca I do it then? Any ideas? Remember, I cant use boost, STL, etc. AND Stuff class HAVE TO be defined AFTER a List class. I just dont know...

Comment: This is ridiculous. How can teachers prohibit using C++ standard library when writing C++? Ask them to write a program that prints "Hello World" without using standard Java packages like `System.*` etc, JNI is not allowed either.

Comment: gcc won't compile this code, for similar reasons to what you mention in the quote.

Comment: "Stuff class HAVE TO be defined AFTER a List class". Is that <our teacher's requirement or is it that you think it should be that way?

Comment: @VladLazarenko The teacher should have prohibited posting the homework assignment to SO to get someone else to write it.

Comment: @jrok : Where did i wrote that I think this should be correct? I googled it almost everywhere and read that is not acceptable in C++... but I wonder, if I can make it in C++ anyway ..

Comment: @VladLazarenko - When learning data structures, writing your own can help you to understand them.

Comment: @BrianBrown I just wanted to clarify. You can make it, but you don't need to.

Comment: @VladLazarenko - This is not ridiculous. Learning how to implement a linked list is important. Learning how to separate declaration from implementation is important. This assignment achieves both.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer, absolutely true.  This is why i see so many programmers use basic constructs but have no idea how to implement them or how they work.  One could proffer the argument that they shouldn't know - but a good engineer will be able to choose the right tool for the job because they know how they *work*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make this code work, you need to define `Stuff` before you define the `List` class constructors and desctructors.

So:

```
class Stuff;

class List
{
    private :

        Stuff *s;
        int n;

    public :
        List(int n);
        ~List();

};

class Stuff
{
    private :

        string name;
        double price;

    public :

        Stuff(){}
};

List::~List()
{
    delete[] s;
    s = NULL;
    n = 0;
}
List::List(int n)
{
    this->n = n;
    s = new Stuff[n];
}
```

Comment: Apparently the requirements are that class Stuff must be defined after class List.

Comment: It is in my example. The constructors and destructors of the class ISN'T. But unless we want code that doesn't compile or is a lot more complicated, I don't see a reasonable solution for that. I don't think it's reasonable to expect the student to rewrite the compiler in a way that extends/alters the way the language works. For `new Stuff[n]` to work, `Stuff` must be a completely defined class.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will make it as you suggested, many thanks!:)

Comment: [And not write a new compiler, you mean? ;)]

Answer (score 3):

What about templates?

```c
template<class T>
class List
{
private :

    T *s;
    int n;

public :

    List(int n)
    {
        this->n = n;
        s = new T[n];
    }

    ~List()
    {
        delete[] s;
        s = NULL;
        n = 0;
    }
};

class Stuff
{
private :

    string name;
    double price;

public :

    Stuff(){}
    ~Stuff(){}
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    List<Stuff> list(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @brian I like this game!  Everyone tries to guess what you want and you just keep saying Nope!  It's fun and I've nothing else to do.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `List` declaration in a header and put implementation into a source file, where `Stuff` definition is available (`#include "Stuff.h"`) and you can delete `Stuff`

Or you can just implement `List` in the same file, but after `Stuff` declaration, so compiler actually knows what to delete

Answer (score 1):

Where you have `class Stuff;` replace it with the actual implemented code. `class Stuff;` is a forward declaration, it mean you can refer to `class Stuff` but you can not use it.

Here are a two solution:

---

```
class Stuff {
private :
    string name;
    double price;
public :
    Stuff(){}
};

class List
{
private :
    Stuff *s;
    int n;
public :
    List(int n) {
        this->n = n;
        s = new Stuff[n];
    }
    ~List() {
        delete[] s;
        s = NULL;
        n = 0;
    }
};
```

---

```
class Stuff;

class List
{
private :
    Stuff *s;
    int n;
public :
    List(int n);
    ~List();
}

class Stuff {
private :
    string name;
    double price;
public :
    Stuff(){}
};

List::List(int n) {
    this->n = n;
    s = new Stuff[n];
}
List::~List() {
    delete[] s;
    s = NULL;
    n = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the declaration from the implementation. While you can't use boost etc., you can use separate header and source files.

Put the definition of class `List` in in list.hh, the definition of class `Stuff` in stuff.hh. In the definition of class `List` (in list.hh), declare but do not define those member functions that need to know about class `Stuff`. Put those function definitions in a source file, list.cpp. This source file will #include both list.hh and stuff.hh.